# How can I get Android device log(logcat) with robot Framework and Appium?

Tags: android, ios, testing, appium, robotframework

I'm using Robot framework and Appium for Android and ios app test.
What I am trying to do is get device log(logcat) for my app's external library API is working fine. 
Is there anyway to capture and confirm the result with Robot Framework and Appium?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using appium with python.
Try this:

```
logs = self.driver.get_log('logcat')
        log_messages = list(map(lambda log: log['message'], logs))
        num = len(log_messages)
        print("num:!", num)
        for i in range(num):
            print((log_messages[i]))
```

This can get logical from android.